# Draggable object jumps a bit when I try to highlight a button

Tags: swift, drag-and-drop

I have 2 UIImageView who are placed on storyboard and setup in code via frames. I have also a UIButton and an optional draggableView: UIView?. What I'm trying to do:

1. Drag a view - seems to be working fine
2. Highlight my button when I hover draggableView over it and disable highlight if we moving away from it. Highlight seems to be happening, but my draggableView goes kinda underneath a button and does a very noticeable jump into its starting position before dragging. After that if we continue dragging - position continues to update properly.

Here is the code for touches

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        ...
        img01.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        img02.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        ...
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else {return}
        
        if img01.bounds.contains(touch.location(in: img01)) {
            draggableView = img01
        } else if img02.bounds.contains(touch.location(in: img02)) {
            draggableView = img02
        }
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let draggableView = draggableView else {return}
        guard let touch = touches.first else {return}
        
        draggableView.center = touch.location(in: view)
        
        if btnMain.bounds.contains(touch.location(in: btnMain)) {
            print("Case 4")
            btnMain.isHighlighted = true
        } else {
            print("Case 5")
            btnMain.isHighlighted = false
        }
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        draggableView = nil
        btnMain.isHighlighted = false
    }
```

What causes that jump to initial position and is there a way to kinda... make draggableView noticeably on top of anything? Thanks.

Comment: "draggableView goes kinda underneath a button" - 
Was the button added after the `draggableView` in the storyboard? If yes, you should add the draggableView after the button.

Comment: @Anwuna Yeah, issue there was with placement. Bringing draggableView to front solved that. Weird jump in position is still there.

Comment: It's hard for me to know what the problem is exactly without adding https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.